# Sprintf is concatenating values

Tags: c, printf

I have the following piece of code in C:

```
value1 = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
value2 = value1 + strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)/2;
value3 = value2+1;
value4 = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);

char inf1[4] = "";
char sup1[4] = "";
char inf2[4] = "";
char sup2[4] = "";

sprintf(inf1, "%d", value1);
sprintf(sup1, "%d", value2);
sprintf(inf2, "%d", value3);
sprintf(sup2, "%d", value4);

printf("Value1: %d\n", value1);
printf("Value2: %d\n", value2);
printf("Inf1: %s\n", inf1);
printf("Sup1: %s\n", sup2);

printf("Value3: %d\n", value3);
printf("Value3: %d\n", value);
printf("Inf2: %s\n", inf2);
printf("Sup2: %s\n", sup2);
```

When I execute my program like this:

> ./program 1000 2000

I receive the following result:

```
Value1: 1000
Value2: 1500
Inf1: 1000150015012000
Sup1: 150015012000

Value3: 1501
Value4: 2000
Inf1: 15012000
Inf2: 2000
```

Somehow, sprintf is randomly concatenating the values and I don't know how to fix it. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char inf1[4] = "";
char sup1[4] = "";
char inf2[4] = "";
char sup2[4] = "";
```

Make these array sizes bigger.

To store "1000" using sprintf it requires 5 bytes. The extra byte is for `\0` - string terminator.

Your program has undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: Or perhaps "never use `sprintf`", it's dangerous for exactly this reason.

Comment: I had to convert from int to char so I could send those params in an execlp call and `sprintf` was the best answer in some other StackOverflow questions. What do you suggest to use instead? Thanks!